# In a finite Abelian group, prove that $\frac{|a|\cdot|b|}{(|a|,|b|)^2} \mid |ab| \mid \frac{|a|\cdot|b|}{(|a|,|b|)}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Stuck with that task for a couple of days. Appreciate any help.

$G$ is a finite Abelian group. $a,b \in G$. $n$ and $m$ are the orders of $a$ and $b$ respectively. $d = (|a|,|b|) = (n,m)$ is the greatest common divisor of $|a|$ and $|b|$.

Prove that:

1. For $d = 1$, $|ab| = mn$.
2. For $d > 1$, $\frac{nm}{d^2} \mid |ab| \mid \frac{nm}{d}$.

The first one seem kinda intuitive, but I still don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: Well, I'll add some thoughts in the comments.
G is abelian, so if we let $x = |ab|$, $(ab)^x = 1 => a^x b^x = 1 => a^x = b^(-x)$

Comment: We also know that in any group we can solve equations like $y = kx$. So, there is a natural number $(t - 1)$ such that $a^x * b^x = a ^ x * (a * (t - 1)) ^ x$ or $(ab) ^x = a^{tx}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e$ be the identity element and $p=|ab|$.

1. Since $G$ is Abelian, $(ab)^{mn} = a^{mn}b^{mn}=e$. So $p| mn$. Then $p\leq mn$. Now, use the division algorithm so that $p = qn+r, 0\leq r< n$. Then $$e = (ab)^{pm} = a^{pm} b^{pm} = a^{pm} = a^{qnm+rm}= a^{rm}$$. Thus, $n| rm$. Since $(n,m)=1$, then $n|r$. But $0\leq r< n$. This means $r=0$ and so $p=qn$. Then $n|p$. Similarly, $m|p$. So $mn=lcm(m,n)\leq p. $ Therefore, $p=mn$.
2. Since $G$ is abelian, $(ab)^{mn/d} = a^{n(m/d)}b^{m(n/d)} = e$. So $p| (mn)/d$ because $m/d,n/d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Next, observe that $(n/d,m/d)=1$. Also, $|a^d| = n/d$ and $|b^d|=m/d$. By 1, $|(ab)^d| = |a^db^d| = (mn)/d^2$.  Now, $[(ab)^d]^p = (ab)^{pd} = e$. Hence, $p$ divides $|(ab)^d|= (mn)/d^2$.

Comment: I guess you meant $lcm$, not "$lcd$".